# Vector of parents and childs C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I want to make a vector of parent and child elements. I tested my code with only one child and that works nice. But when i added one more child (`Child2`), i see a problem.
When i try to get value of `px` expected output is : 5 7 11, but i get value of `type` variable (2);

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Helper.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    std::vector<Parent*> arr1;
    arr1.push_back(new Child(3, 4, 5, 6));
    arr1.push_back(new Parent(7, 8));
    arr1.push_back(new Child2(9, 10, 11, 12));

    std::cout << static_cast<Universal*>(arr1.at(0))->dx << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<Universal*>(arr1.at(1))->x << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<Universal*>(arr1.at(2))->px << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Helper.cpp**

```
#include "Helper.h"

Parent::Parent(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Child::Child(int x, int y, int dx, int dy) : Parent(x, y) {
    this->dx = dx;
    this->dy = dy;
}

Child2::Child2(int x, int y, int px, int py) : Parent(x, y) {
    this->px = px;
    this->py = py;
}

Universal::Universal(int x, int y) : Parent(x, y) {}
```

**Helper.h**

```
class Parent {
public:
    int x, y;
    int type = 0;

    Parent(int x, int y);
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    int dx, dy;
    int type = 1;

    Child(int x, int y, int dx, int dy);
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    int px, py;
    int type = 2;

    Child2(int x, int y, int px, int py);
};

class Universal : public Parent {
public:
    int dx, dy, px, py;

    Universal(int x, int y);
};
```

Comment: You have UB with your `static_cast<Universal*>`.

Comment: Storing raw pointers in a `std::vector` (or any STL container for that matter) is nearly always a bad idea. Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>>` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 , what is UB?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You claim that `Parent`, `Child1` and `Child2` are `Universal`, which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Universal` is not a parent or child of `Child2`. As such, the `static_cast` will not work.

Child2 has the following class members:

```
int    int    int
 px     py    type
```

Universal, on the other hand, contains the following class members:

```
int    int    int    int
 dx      dy    px     py
```

And that's why when the code reads `px`, it ends up getting the value of `type`. Your compiler simply places each class member, consecutively as part of its class, irrespective of the name of the class member. `type` in one of the classes ends up occupting the same relative position, the offset, from the beginning of the class, in memory, as `px` in the other one. The classes contain `int` class members. `type` is the third `int` in one of the classes, and `type` is the third `int` in the other one.

Just because two classes have a class member of the same name it doesn't mean that the class member will have the same internal position in memory, as the member of its class.

In fact, the C++ standard doesn't really give you many guarantees. That there's no guarantee that class members will be arranged in any particular order, in memory, anyway. There are actually a few rules there, but they're irrelevant for the purpose of this question.

Even if both classes have their fields listed, in a class declaration, in some particular order, one should not end up relying on the fact that a very rude `static_cast` will end up with a different class with the fields with the same name having the same values as the other class.

The correct solution for what you're trying to do is to use `virtual` class methods.

Comment: Thanks! I created virtual methods getDX, DY, PX, PY, getType and that solved my problem.